# Initialize a high chart in View

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, highcharts

I am trying to display high chart in partial view but getting Error 16. In main view

```
 @using Highsoft.Web.Mvc.Charts

 {
 @(Html.Highsoft().Highcharts(
    new Highcharts
        {}
),"container1")
```

is displays fine but when I try to laod the graph in Partial view using the same code

```
 @using Highsoft.Web.Mvc.Charts

 {
 @(Html.Highsoft().Highcharts(
    new Highcharts
        {}
),"container2")
```

It gives error as the high charts are already initialized. I am new to high charts. Please guide me how to initialize the high charts once so that I can reuse in partial view. Thanks

Comment: Here's a sample project that uses PartialView: https://nofile.io/f/9MkAy4N2eS0/PartialViewSample.zip Maybe it'll help you.

Comment: Thanks for the SAMPLE but you did not get my point. When my page loads first time It loads a graph from Index function in container div.
 and in that Index View I have a button 

   @Ajax.ActionLink("display", "getGraph", "Dashboard", null, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "GET", LoadingElementId = "divLoading", UpdateTargetId = "container", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary" })
and getGraph return a Partial view
return PartialView("~/Views/Dashboard/_displayPrDrillDown.cshtml");

Comment: and In Partial View
@Html.Highsoft().GetHighcharts(chart2, "chart2")
When I debug it I can see the container Div and inside container div I can see chart2 div as well BUT Chart2 DIV is empty.... and under chart 2 there is
<script>
 tag where chart is defined but not displayed on the page

Comment: @Kamil Kulig.... I added a button on Index view you sent and added another div on the index view to display the partial view in that div on button clieck but the partial view never get rendered in that view. All I get is the div and inside that div I get <div id="chart3"> and this div is empty I and <script language="javascript"> and inside script I get all the markup for chart but chart never get displayed in the partial view.

Comment: Try changing `GetHighcharts` to `GetHighchartsJS`. Here's a demo that uses Ajax and `GetHighchartsJS`: https://nofile.io/f/H9kJGwm3Pv5/AjaxSample.zip

Comment: @Kamil Kulig...Thanks for the sample again..It worked but please hav a look as its not rendering the partial view in main page and render it in a new page..  
https://nofile.io/f/DXBR6tXycov/TestCharts.zip

Comment: First download `Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax` from NuGet. Then you have to add the following code to use `@Ajax.ActionLink` properly: `<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>`

Comment: @Kamil Kulig...Thanks ....Could you please have a look at my other question and suggest me an answer  ......https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50693693/opening-a-column-chart-after-clinking-on-drilledown-pie-charts-in-dotnet-highcha